# MySQL query to group results by hour of day, taking into account daylight savings

Tags: mysql, group-by, dst

I have a report that uses a an sql query similar to this:

```
SELECT HOUR(somedatetime) AS hour, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM table
GROUP BY HOUR(surveyenddatetime)
```

I've simplified it here by leaving out the where clause that can limit the results to a given time period.  It works quite nicely for getting the total records grouped by hour of day they were entered for the time period selected.

However, it has one fatal flaw.  When the time period selected includes records not in the same 'timezone' as the user running the report, such as records from before daylight savings and records after daylight savings, it doesn't work.  All records are stored in GMT/UTC on in the datetime fields and converted to local times in php via the web front end.  But this query runs before any of that happens and php has no way of knowing what the original dates where for the totals grouped into each hour.

Is there a way I can solve this query to take daylight savings into account using just a MySQL query or am I going to have to do something more complicated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`CONVERT_TZ`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz):

```
SELECT 
    HOUR(CONVERT_TZ(`somedatetime`, 'UTC', 'Europe/Amsterdam')) AS `hour`, 
    COUNT(*) AS `count`
FROM table
GROUP BY `hour`
```

Pass the user's timezone into the query in place of 'Europe/Amsterdam'.

See also: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-tzinfo-to-sql.html (You may need to intialise MySQL with timezone data.)

Comment: This isn't right. The records need to return the hour for their own timezone, not the users.  So if I had one record from 09:00 GMT from say March 1st, and another 09:00 BST from April 4th, they both show up in the total for '9'.

Comment: I thought you said the records had been stored in UTC? So they'd have been converted on the way into the DB?

Comment: Yes, for consistency they are all stored in UTC. But for the report I need records in daylight savings to return the hour in their local time (ie +1).

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "records in daylight savings" - they're either in UTC or a local timezone. If everything is stored in UTC it doesn't matter what timezone it came from. i.e. user logs in at 10pm US Eastern, which is converted to a UTC timestamp, and then retrieved from the log by a user in another timezone as a time local to that user.

Comment: Actually, it maybe that I didn't understand your answer. When I first looked, it seemed like you misunderstood my question.  Now I suspect it may be the other way around.  I'll try your solution and see if it works... :)

Comment: Sorry about that, your solution was totally correct. My brain must have been playing up as I just couldn't believe the answer could be that simple at first!

Comment: Haha, well it is getting late in the day. Especially after losing an hour ;)